# Loop through multidimensional array and then display results

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to build a form with drop downs that will query a json object with jQuery and then display that product with its data on my html page depending on what was chosen in the drop downs.

Here is my json object:

```
var obj = {
            "ProductOne":
            {
                "url":["http://www.google.com"],
                "map":["test-one"],
                "options":["test-one","test-three","test-four"],
                "dim":{
                    "bam":"5",
                    "tin":"4"
                },
                "acc":{
                    "bam":"1",
                    "tin":"2"
                }
            },
            "ProductTwo":
            {
                "url":["http://www.google-two.com"],
                "map":["test-two"],
                "options":["test-two","test-three","test-five"],
                "dim":{
                    "bam":"6",
                    "tin":"9"
                },
                "acc":{
                    "bam":"8",
                    "tin":"6"
                }
            }
        };
```

Here is my form:

```
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm">

        <select name="dim">
            <option value="" selected="">Select One</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
        <select name="acc">
            <option value="" selected="">Select One</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
        <select name="options">
            <option value="" selected="">Select One</option>
            <option value="test-one">Test One</option>
            <option value="test-two">Test Two</option>
            <option value="test-three">Test Three</option>
            <option value="test-four">Test Four</option>
            <option value="test-five">Test Five</option>
        </select>
        <input id="button" type="button" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you explain what didn't work in your attempt to solve the problem? Can you post a live demo? Help us help you.

Comment: How do you want the results to be shown? in a table? or how?

Comment: @elclanrs i tried using jQuery.each to loop through it and then display it on my page.

Comment: @Edgar i want the products name and url to be displayed in div tags (ie...<div class="title">ProductOne<br/><a href="url">url</a></div>)

Comment: @user I added an answer with all you want :)

Comment: @Edgar i tried to apply the filter. I changed the submit button to a button and i added .click(function()) but it doesnt filter at all, it just shows both products all the time? I updated my object and my form to better reflect a filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with this:

```
var filteredProducts = {},
    dim = $("select[name=dim]").val(),
    acc = $("select[name=acc]").val(),
    option = $("select[name=options]").val();

function valueInObject(object, value){
   for(var key in object){
      if(object[key] == value) return true;
   }
   return false;      
}

$.each(obj, function(key, product){
    if(
      (option == "" || $.inArray(option, product.options)) >= 0 && 
      (acc == "" || valueInObject(product.acc, acc)) &&
      (dim == "" || valueInObject(product.dim, dim))   
    ){
       filteredProducts[key] = product;
    }
});

console.log(filteredProducts);
alert(JSON.stringify(filteredProducts));
```

Then, you have the filtered products in the `filteredProducts` object, that has same structure as the original `obj` object.
Then you can traverse it and show it in a table or something.

Assuming you want to show them on a list, let's say you have:

```
<div id="filteredProducts"></div>
```

you would do:

```
$('#filteredProducts').empty();  //Clears previous results
$.each(filteredProducts, function(productKey, product){
    $('<div class="title">'+productKey+'<br/>'+
          '<a href="'+ product.url+'">'+ product.url + '</a>'+
      '</div>').appendTo('#filteredProducts');
});
```

It would add each product to the list.

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: thanks! i tried to apply the filter. I changed the submit button to a button and i added .click(function()) but it doesnt filter at all, it just shows both products all the time?

Comment: ok, its working now thank you...but in the options drop down when i choose Test One ProductTwo shows up and when i choose Test Two ProductOne shows up???

Comment: Right, does it have to filter by the `map` property of obj OR by the `options` array ?

Comment: I updated the answer, there was a small error in the `$.inArray` line. Here the demo http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/V8CTV/2/  *Note:* I'm igonring the `map` property, I'm filtering by the `options` array

Comment: btw if you wanted to filter with the map property instead of options, just change `$.inArray(option, product.options))` by `$.inArray(option, product.map))` Cheers

Comment: one more question? how do i filter it if the value is less than or greater than the selection?

Comment: Ok :). For example, which value would you like to be greater than what?

Comment: display the products who's dim value is less than or equal to the selection. if 9 was chosen display the products with a dim value that is less than or equal to 9.

Comment: but there are 2 dims, `bam` and `tin`, which one?

Comment: ok. Instead of `valueInObject(product.dim, dim)` you'd have `parseInt(product.dim.bam) <= parseInt(dim)`. That's it :)

Comment: im sorry but that didnt work...this is wahat i have (dim == "" || parseInt(product.dim.bam) <= parsInt(dim))

Comment: please check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/V8CTV/12/. when you choose 1.20 for dim, ProductOne and ProductTwo show up, but only ProductOne should show up.

Comment: Oh, if you have decimals also use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Comment: yes...i figured it out...thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Welcome. Cheers from La Paz, Bolivia :)

Comment: (If StackOverflow allows you, please also upvote my answer. Thanks :))